# Android :How to change simple_list_item_1 in grid view

Tags: android

I am trying to replace **"simple_list_item_1"** file with my custom layout file. But it is showing error . How to change simple_list_item_1  in grid view ?

```
public class TestNumbers extends Activity {

        GridView gridView;

        static final String[] numbers = new String[] {
                "a", "b", "b", "d", "e",
              };

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.number);

            gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

             ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers){
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            String value = getItem(position);
            if (value.equals("a")) {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            } else {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
            // Updating the text color.
            TextView textView= (TextView) view;
            textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            return view;
        }
    };

            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

            gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                        int position, long id) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            ((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            });
```

I just added below code and able to change background color . How to change shape and cell distance in below code?

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers){
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                String value = getItem(position);
                if (value.equals("a")) {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                } else {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }
                // Updating the text color.
                TextView textView= (TextView) view;
                textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                return view;
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your custom `Adapter`. You have an example in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

Comment: example is showing with Image view and I don't want to pass any image to grid . Just working with text value .

Comment: The example is just that: an example. You can inflate any layout you want inside the adapter's `getView()`. You can find another tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

The parent of layout you given to the adapter must be `TextView`. So replace your list item layout with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</TextView>
```

Comment: I have two xml file . one is for grid view  and other is for grid_view_item . grid_view_item.xml has textview and it is showing error.

Comment: Is your `grid_view_item.xml` only has `TextView`?

Comment: Can you post your log?

Comment: Yes. It only has TextView.